# Optimize PLSQL Cursor Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, cursors

I am making a HTML report by embedding html into PLSQL. I've done this by 2 cursors and nested loops but i want to optimize it. My Oracle Apex report is generating this output

```
ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK
King - President
Clark - Manager
Miller - Clerk
RESEARCH - DALLAS
Jones - Manager
Scott - Analyst
Ford - Analyst
Smith - Clerk
Adams - Clerk
SALES - CHICAGO
Blake - Manager
Allen - Salesman
Ward - Salesman
Martin - Salesman
Turner - Salesman
James - Clerk
OPERATIONS - BOSTON
No Employee
```

my code is

```
    declare
Cursor c_dept Is Select d.Deptno,d.Dname,d.Loc
      From  eba_demo_load_dept d;

   Cursor c_Emp(v_Deptno Number) Is Select e.Empno,e.Ename,e.Job
      From   eba_demo_load_emp e
      Where  e.Deptno = v_Deptno;
begin

 For i In c_Dept Loop

      Htp.p('<ul>');
      Htp.p('<h4>' || i.Dname ||' - '||i.loc||'</h4>');
      --
      For j In c_Emp(i.Deptno) Loop
        Htp.p('<li>' || initcap(j.Ename) || ' - ' ||initcap(j.job)||'</li>');       
      End Loop;
    Htp.p('</ul>');    
   End Loop;

  Htp.p('<p>No Employee </p>');

end;
```

I want to optimize it. Is it possible to achieve same output in one loop with inner join in cursor variable. If yes please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single cursor by combining the queries as follows:

```
declare
Cursor c_dept Is 
Select d.Deptno,d.Dname,d.Loc,,
           Listagg('<li>' || initcap(j.Ename) || ' - ' ||initcap(j.job)||'</li>', chr(10))
             Within group (order by 1) as emps
      From eba_demo_load_dept d
      Join eba_demo_load_emp e
      On e.Deptno = d.Deptno
      Group by d.Deptno,d.Dname,d.Loc;

begin

 For i In c_Dept Loop

      Htp.p('<ul>');
      Htp.p('<h4>' || i.Dname ||' - '||i.loc||'</h4>');
      --

    Htp.p(i.emps);       

    Htp.p('</ul>');    
   End Loop;

  Htp.p('<p>No Employee </p>');

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that nested cursor loops - in this case - does what it is supposed to do. Because of different HTML tags, I don't think that other solutions would make it any better; maybe slightly more difficult to read and understand. The way it is now, it is perfectly clear what you are doing and what you expect as a result.

However, is there any particular reason **why** you are doing it this way? Apex offers Interactive and Classic Reports which do that easily, in a matter of a few clicks. I'd suggest you to use one of these instead of your own code.

Comment: Yeah you are right but I need to built complex interfaces like profile details or some card based complex reports. So need to use HTML/CSS with that.